# How to implement drag and drop with flutter

Tags: flutter

How can I move my container or any other widgets on flutter around the screen and drop at some locations?

I found flutter widgets `Draggable` and `DragTarget`. How to use them to implement the drag and drop?

Answer (score 9):

`Draggable` and `DragTarget` allow us to drag a widget across the screen.
A `Draggable` widgets gives the ability to move to any other widget while the `DragTarget` acts as the sink or drop location for a `Draggable` widget.

Find the below code sample using which I implemented a simple odd-or-even game

> *Hell yeah, I'm a Game Developer ◕‿↼*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

class OddOrEven extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _OddOrEvenState();
  }
}

class _OddOrEvenState extends State<OddOrEven> {
  bool accepted = false;
  Color dotColor = Colors.blue;
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey();

  int val = 0;
  int score = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    // assign a random number to value which will be used as the box value
    val = Random().nextInt(100);
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[

            // just a score and mock player name indicator
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Center(
                child: Center(
                  child: Chip(
                    avatar: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
                      child: Text(
                        score.toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                    label: Text(
                      'Player Alpha',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),


            // here comes our draggable.
            // it holds data which is our random number
            // the child of the draggable is a container reactangural in shape and 
            //
            Draggable(
              data: val,
              child: Container(
                width: 100.0,
                height: 100.0,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    val.toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 22.0),
                  ),
                ),
                color: Colors.pink,
              ),

              // This will be displayed when the widget is being dragged
              feedback: Container(
                width: 100.0,
                height: 100.0,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    val.toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 22.0),
                  ),
                ),
                color: Colors.pink,
              ),
              // You can also specify 'childWhenDragging' option to draw
              // the original widget changes at the time of drag.

            ),


            // and here this row holds our two DragTargets. 
            // One for odd numbers and the other for even numbers.
            //
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[

                Container(
                  width: 100.0,
                  height: 100.0,
                  color: Colors.green,

                  // Even holder DragTarget
                  //
                  child: DragTarget(
                    builder: (context, List<int> candidateData, rejectedData) {
                      print(candidateData);
                      return Center(
                          child: Text(
                        "Even",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 22.0),
                      ));
                    },

                    // On will accept gets called just before it accepts the drag source.
                    // if needed, we can reject the data here. But we are not doing that as this is a GAME !!! :)
                    onWillAccept: (data) {
                      print("Will accpt");
                      return true; //return false to reject it
                    },

                    // On accepting the data by the DragTarget we simply check whether the data is odd or even and accept based on that and increment the counter and rebuild the widget tree for a new random number at the source.
                    onAccept: (data) {
                      print("On accpt");
                      if (data % 2 == 0) {

                        setState(() {
                          score++;
                        });
                        // How did you manage to score 3 points
                        // Congrats. You won the game.
                        if (score >= 3) {
                          showDialog(
                              context: context,
                              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                return new AlertDialog(
                                  title: Text("Congrats!!"),
                                  content: Text("No-brainer..."),
                                  actions: <Widget>[
                                    FlatButton(
                                      child: Text("Ok."),
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                        setState(() {
                                          score = 0;
                                        });
                                      },
                                    )
                                  ],
                                );
                              });
                        }
                      } else {
                        setState(() {});

                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ),

                // And here is the Odd-holder
                Container(
                  width: 100.0,
                  height: 100.0,
                  color: Colors.deepPurple,
                  child: DragTarget(
                    builder: (context, List<int> candidateData, rejectedData) {
                      return Center(
                          child: Text(
                        "Odd",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 22.0),
                      ));
                    },
                    onWillAccept: (data) {
                      return true;
                    },
                    onAccept: (data) {
                      if (data % 2 != 0) {

                        setState(() {
                          score++;
                        });

                        if (score >= 10) {
                          showDialog(
                              context: context,
                              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                return new AlertDialog(
                                  title: Text("Congrats!!"),
                                  content: Text("No-brainer..."),
                                  actions: <Widget>[
                                    FlatButton(
                                      child: Text("Thanks"),
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                        setState(() {
                                          score = 0;
                                        });
                                      },
                                    )
                                  ],
                                );
                              });
                        }
                      } else {
                        setState(() {});

                      }
                    },
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry - I'm a noob at this. What do I need to do in order to run the above? Does it need a main() function, or ...?

Comment: @user3012629 Please follow flutter.dev 's developement introduction. https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets-intro  TL;DR: inside main function, use runApp(OddOrEven() ); for a quick run.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to drop at a non-fixed location (Draggable without a DragTarget), this can also be implemented with Stack()/Positioned() using renderbox sizing, as per [How to move element anywhere inside parent container with drag and drop in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57080144/how-to-move-element-anywhere-inside-parent-container-with-drag-and-drop-in-flutt/58682175#58682175)